# Saving WPF Adorners

Tags: wpf, adorner

I am relatively new to WPF and I have an issue with Adorners.

I have an inkcanvas that contains an image, I can save the image with the strokes added by the user.  The issue I have is that I have a requirement that allows the user to add text over the image, and to print/save the text without damaging th image.

I used an adorner to put text over the inkcanvas, and it looks fine on screen, but I am at a loss to save the text, or print the image with the text.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Josh Smith had provided two great articles towards Image Annotations. I think this is something you've been looking for:

CodeProject: [Annotating an Image in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AnnotatingAnImageInWPF.aspx)

Josh Smith blog: [Annotating an Image in a Viewbox](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/26/annotating-an-image-in-a-viewbox/)

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/mehlhorn/archive/2006/03/11/549132.aspx) article will give you a brief overview of Annotation Framework in WPF and the ways annotations can be persisted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to save the annotation text to an image?